# "mArrayAdapter cannot be resolved" in Android bluetooth project.

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, bluetooth

I am developing a bluetooth app for android on the 2.2 platform. I have two instances of mArrayAdapter in my code, and both of them cannot be resolved. My code is almost exactly the same as the code on the Android dev site, because I used it as an example. I have tried defining the variables locally, but then I get an error on .add after mArrayAdapter. I have found articles that have similar issues, but none of their answers have worked for me. I think that I have to define it somewhere, but there is not any notation about that I have found online. I will paste some of by code below. Thanks.

```
     //Find the paired Devices
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
//If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
 // Loop through paired devices
 for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
     // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
     //---------------------> ERROR BELOW <------------------------
     mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

 }
}
// Discovering Bluetooth Devices.
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        //When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device =   intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //Log.v("bluetooth Tesing",device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in ListView. 
            //---------------------> ERROR BELOW <------------------------
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() +"\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Sample Bluetooth Chat, DeviceListActivity which you are using as a templete, you will see that the **two** ArrayAdapter adapters are both declared as member variables in the class (hence the 'm' prefix) near the top of the class. They are both instantiated with

```
 m?????ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
```

in the onCreate. You need to do something analagous for your **one** adapter before trying to add an item to it.

Comment: I added in the code you specified, but have to change device_name to main. Eclipse will only let me use main there. That solved my problems with mArrayAdapter. Now I have a problem with a few other lines that have the error "Unhandled exception type IOException". I dug around on my own again but could not find a solution. I don't understand why changing a declaration for an unrelated variable has an effect on multiple other lines of code.